# Подгрузка постов ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, ajax-load

Есть блоки, которые генерируются foreach по WP_Query.
Ограничил вывод до штук. Необходимо сделать подгрузку следующих по клику. Что нужно передать в обработчик ajax и как генерировать или что возвращать в data от обработчика. Каким образом правильно написать этот механизм?

Comment: Нужен параметр лимит оффсет (как пагинация), чтобы при клике на кнопку подгрузки были критерии по которым вы будете отбирать следующие блоки, напри всего 10 блоков, вы отдаете по 2, нужен будет идентификатор страницы, и вручную отдавать новые элементы массива

Comment: Как мне обратно от обработчика отдавать html сгенерированный в ajax?

Comment: Не знаю, как на вордпрессе это делается. Например в ларавель можно отдать view('name', $params)->render(), во вьюхе будет отрендереный кусок html кода с Вашими параметрами, который просто нужно будет вставить с помощью jQuery $('block').html(response.html);

Comment: Есть подробный отличный ответ на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress

Comment: Из любого ajax-обработчика вы отдаете данные простым выводом через echo, print, print_r и пр.

Answer (score 0):

Код запроса будет приблизительно похож на это

```
function my_ajax_data(){
$category_id= $_POST['cat'];
$offset= $_POST['offset'];
args = array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'category'    => $category_id,
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'offset' => $offset, // число  постов которое вы пропускаете перед новым запросом
    'posts_per_page' => -1,

);
```

далее получаем наши посты

```
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

и собираем хтмл (хотя это можно сделать и на js кому как удобнее)

```
$html.='<div>'.$post->post_title.'</div>';
```

и возвращаем его в js

```
print $html;
wp_die();
}
```

P.S это только бекэнд сторона. и крайне приблизительный код

Comment: <a href="<?=the_permalink($post->ID);?>" class="blog__card__inner">
Как такую строку можно записать в $html. = ?

Comment: $html='<a href="'.get_the_permalink($post->ID).'" class="blog__card__inner">';